# How to fix undefined reference to `__imp_WSACleanup' (Boost.Asio) in CLion

Tags: c++, boost, clion

My C++ project includes [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) and [WebSocket++](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp) libs. I read other topics I need to add `-lws2_32` to gcc command, but I've CLion and I don't know how to fix it.

Console:

```
CMakeFiles\WsServer.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::startup(boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::data&, unsigned char, unsigned char)':
C:/MinGW/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp:39: undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup'
CMakeFiles\WsServer.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::cleanup(boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_base::data&)':
C:/MinGW/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp:56: undefined reference to `__imp_WSACleanup'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\WsServer.dir\build.make:99: WsServer.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:67: CMakeFiles/WsServer.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:79: CMakeFiles/WsServer.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: WsServer] Error 2
```

What I should do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can pass `ws2_32` via `target_link_libraries` in your CMakeLists.txt, e.g.:

```
if(MINGW)
  target_link_libraries(YourTargetName ws2_32)
endif()
```